# How to convert one XML file into another using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How to transform this XML file:

```
<file>
  <text ID="201" date="2014-05-04">
    <user_name>user_11</user_name>
    <message> HELLO </message>
  </text>
</file>
```

into this XML file by using XSLT 1.0:

```
<doc>
  <user name="user_11">
    <text id="201" date="2014-05-04"> HELLO </text> 
  </user>
</doc>
```

Also if you have any resources on the subject, please post because I have a lot more of XSLT file to code. thanks

Comment: I have rolled back your question to its original form, otherwise the answers do not make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <doc>
        <xsl:for-each select="file/text">
            <user name="{user_name}">
                <text id="{@ID}" date="{@date}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="message" />
                </text> 
            </user>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </doc>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a files container in your `XML`, anyway you are looking for something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <docs>
    <xsl:for-each select="files/file">
      <xsl:element name="doc">
        <xsl:element name="text">
         <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="text/user_name" />
         </xsl:attribute>  
          <xsl:element name="text">
           <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="text/@ID" />
           </xsl:attribute> 
           <xsl:attribute name="date">
            <xsl:value-of select="text/@date" />
           </xsl:attribute> 
           <xsl:value-of select="text/message" />
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>      
      </xsl:element>       
    </xsl:for-each>
  </docs>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XSLT is verbose, but it doesn't need to be *that* verbose. You can output literal elements by writing them directly to the result tree, and you can use the *attribute value template* to shorten your code. http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Creating-Elements-and-Attributes

Comment: @michael.hor257k please post your answer, I'd like to see what do you intend